# Javascript filter not filtering by selection only?

Tags: javascript, php

So I got this code and everytime I filter by selection it goes site.com/brands/brand+++red/ (example of trying to filter by brand +  varietal). Is there a way to make it filter by the marked options only removing the extras "+'s" from the URL?.I tried adding several IF for each ID but I can't make it to remove the extra symbols from the URL. Thanks

```
<div>
                     <h4> TYPE </h4>
                     <?php $firstParent = $parents[2]; ?>
                     <?php $types = get_term_children( $firstParent->term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                     <select name="type" id="type">
                         <option value="">Choose type</option>
                         <?php foreach ( $types as $child ) {
                             $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy ); ?>
                             <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                     </select>
    <br><br>
                     <h4> BRANDS </h4>
                     <?php $firstParent = $parents[0]; ?>
                     <?php $brands = get_term_children( $firstParent->term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                     <select name="brand" id="brand">
                         <option value="">Choose brand</option>
                         <?php foreach ( $brands as $child ) {
                             $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy ); ?>
                             <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                     </select>
    <br><br>
                     <h4> REGION </h4>
                     <?php $firstParent = $parents[1]; ?>
                     <?php $regions = get_term_children( $firstParent->term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                     <select name="region" id="region">
                         <option value="">Choose region</option>
                         <?php foreach ( $regions as $child ) {
                             $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy ); ?>
                             <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                     </select>
    <br><br>
                     <h4> VARIETAL </h4>
                     <?php $firstParent = $parents[3]; ?>
                     <?php $varietals = get_term_children( $firstParent->term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>
                     <select name="varietal" id="varietal">
                         <option value="">Choose varietal</option>
                         <?php foreach ( $varietals as $child ) {
                             $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy ); ?>
                             <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                     </select>
                 <?php endif;?>

            <br>
            <br>
            <button type="button" id="filter">Apply</button>
    </div>


            <script type="text/javascript">

                document.getElementById("filter").onclick = function () {
                    location.href = "<?php echo home_url();?>/brands/" +
                            document.getElementById("type").value + "+" + document.getElementById("brand").value + "+" +
                            document.getElementById("region").value + "+" + document.getElementById("varietal").value;
                };
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("filter").onclick = function() {
  var type = document.getElementById("type")
  var brand = document.getElementById("brand")
  var region = document.getElementById("region")
  var varietal = document.getElementById("varietal")

  var q = '';

  if (type) {
    q = document.getElementById("type").value + '+'
  }
  if (brand) {
     q = q + document.getElementById("brand").value + '+';
  }
  if (region) {
    q = q + document.getElementById("region").value  + '+';
  }
  if (varietal) {
     q = q + document.getElementById("region").value;
  }

  location.href = "<?php echo home_url();?>/brands/" + q;
};
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you please format your code better. It is currently very hard to read

Comment: "I tried adding several IF for each ID"  Can you show this attempt?

Comment: In that attempt, you didn't assign (and then check) the _value_ of the element, you assigned (and checked) _the element itself_.  That means your `if` checks were always true.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks, I'll try to make it check.

Comment: another way `var q = ["type", "brand", "region", "varietal"].map(id => document.getElementById(id).value).filter(Boolean).join("+");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables contain the DOM elements, not their values; these will always be true (unless the DOM elements don't exist). You need to use `.value`.

And instead of concatenating strings, put all the items you want in an array, then use `.join()` to create a string with `+` between them.

```
document.getElementById("filter").onclick = function() {
  var type = document.getElementById("type").value
  var brand = document.getElementById("brand").value
  var region = document.getElementById("region").value
  var varietal = document.getElementById("varietal").value

  var q = [];

  if (type) {
    q.push(type);
  }
  if (brand) {
     q.push(brand);
  }
  if (region) {
    q.push(region);
  }
  if (varietal) {
     q.push(varietal);
  }

  location.href = "<?php echo home_url();?>/brands/" + q.join("+");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value is empty/null for each field, then append, or not, to the url. Better using an array and then "implode" or "join" by your string `+`:

```
var url = "<?php echo home_url();?>/brands/";
var urlParams = [];
if (document.getElementById("type").value != '') {
    urlParams.push(document.getElementById("type").value);
}
if (document.getElementById("brand").value != '') {
    urlParams.push(document.getElementById("brand").value);
}
if (document.getElementById("region").value != '') {
    urlParams.push(document.getElementById("region").value);
}
if (document.getElementById("varietal").value != '') {
    urlParams.push(document.getElementById("varietal").value);
}

location.href = url + urlParams.join('+');
```